# Apache redirects to a different port for every directory

Tags: apache-2.2, varnish

I have configured Apache virtual host to run at port 8000 and in front of Apache I have Varnish on port 80. The problem is if I paste this in my browser:

example.com/a_directory

I am redirected to example.com:8000/a_directory

I get an unable to connect error. In the config file I have this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerAdmin xxx@xxx.org.au

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm 

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What's running on Apache, I'm guessing PHP code from your `DirectoryIndex` settings?  That's likely what's throwing the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly due to self-referential redirects, for example when a trailing slash is missing from a directory request. In such cases, in the absence of a ServerName directive, Apache will use the port that the request came in on - in your case, 8000. In Apache 2.x the ServerName directive supports a port specifier which is used to build redirects. From the Apache docs:

> *The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating redirection URLs.*

In your vhost block add something like (obviously change to your environment) ServerName www.foo.com:80, which should tell Apache to build those redirects using the upstream proxy port as opposed to the port it's listening on.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html for more information on this directive.